# Время проведенное на сайте

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. 
Хочу сделать чтоб пользователь мог видеть сколько времени всего он провел на сайте в онлайн. Но для того чтоб его вывести его нужно записать в базу. Как делать запросы в базу я знаю, только вот не пойму как его записывать в базу.. чтоли при каждом обновлении страницы пользователям запись делать, или как?
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут есть 2 варианта

1) Время проведённое с момента авторизации на сайте

2) Общее время проведённое на сайте

В первом случае, записываем время авторизации в сессию в формате mktime и высчитываем время

Второй вариант описан выше

Answer (score 1):

Для начала определитесь, что значит "время, проведенное на сайте". Если это время между загрузкой и выгрузкой страницы, то просто скриптом на сайте делаете так:

onload - записали текущее время-дату

onunload - отослали на сервер разницу между текущим время-датой и начальным, в секундах, допустим. Плюс ID пользователя.

На стороне сервера по ID пользователя суммируем все цифры.

Но что делать, если время, пока страница открыта в фоновой вкладке и забыта, не хочется считать? Или если сайт открыт в трех вкладках - пользователь в три раза больше проводит там времени?

В общем, начните с определения, с ТЗ для самого себя, и ответ придет.

Comment: пользователь считается онлайн если с момента последнего обновления страницы еще не прошло 5минут. Вот все это время мне нужно считать

Comment: При каждом обновлении страницы - записывайте время в БД. В том месте где будет отображаться онлайн, вычитаете из текущего времени - время которое хранится в БД для текущего пользователя. Ну и если больше 5 минут - офлайн, меньше = онлайн.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно проверять раз в 5 минут, то будет проще делать все это средствами jquery

```
setInterval(function(){
    // такой простой код только для примера
    $.get('/updateTime.php?user=USER_ID')
}, 60000 * 5)
```

Такой асинхронный вариант немного лучше чем каждый раз при обновлении страницы писать в базу. Плюс к тому пользователю не придется обновлять страницы, если он находится на сайте - например медленно читает длинную статью.

Comment: я так понял *$.get('/updateTime.php?user=USER_ID')* это выполняется код из файла **updateTime.phpp** если пользователь онлайн. в этом файле должен быть запрос на добавления времени в базу. правильно??

Comment: да, все верно. Если пользователь на страинце, то скрипт будет вызван и соответсвенно обновлено его время пребывания.

Comment: Но пользователь может не трогать страницу целый день и всё равно будет онлайн с вашим подходом.

Comment: Ну да, на это скрипт и рассчитан. Ведь это и считается за время проведенное на сайте. разве не?